# Obtaning refresh token when using Extenral Data Source with Salesforce OAuth 2

Tags: oauth2, authentication, externalobjects

I'm trying to configure an External Data Source to use Salesforce Auth Provider so the OAuth 2 will pass access and refresh token.
My configuration:
    Identity Type: Per User
    Authentication Protocol: OAuth 2.0
    Authentication Provider test (Salesforce)

Setting scope to refresh_token and saving results in the following error:

> We can’t log you in because of an authentication error. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator.

Setting the scope in the Auth Provider configuration makes Consumer Key and Consumer Secret fields required, defining some values in there and using Test-Only Initialization URL results in the following error:

> error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid

Is there any way to configure External Data Source to use refresh token? Alternatively is there any way for the External Data Source (OData to be precise) to get to know the Salesforce ID of the user that caused the request to be sent to the External Data Source?

Answer (score 0):

If you put refresh_token in the scope it seems to pass it.

Here are the options - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_addl_params_scope.htm&type=5

Your error above isn't about a refresh token though - you need to change how you pass the ClientID (or actually do pass it if you're not..)